# Is this a valid HTTP get request?

Tags: java, http

I am integrating with a system that is sending HTTP-GET requests to our application.  Using Jetty, it took a few minutes to slap something together.

I tested it with curl (with the necessary escapes in the request) and all was rosy.  I got the response back as requested:

```
$ curl http://localhost:9100?field1=value1\&field2=value2\&field3=value3
```

A TCP dump on the machine, shows the request coming through as:

```
GET /?field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.13.1.0 zlib/1.2.3    libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9100
Accept: */*
```

However, life is never that simple.  When I deployed this so that we can actually start integrating with the real system, the handler in my code did not even get called.  Jetty responded with "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" immediately.  A TCP dump revealed the following:

```
GET ?field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3 HTTP/1.1
```

That's it... no header information, just the above.

My question now is whether the request above is actually valid.  Is the slash required? Is any of the header entries compulsory?

Any ideas? Does this mean I have to redesign the wheel to get this working?

---

EDIT:

I tried using telnet to connect.  It seems like the / is indeed required after the GET request for some webservers.  However, it seems it is handled differently between them.  Jetty complains, the webserver that google runs on complains... however Apache is an example of one that is fine with it.  None of the header information seems to be required.

Comment: `http://localhost:9100` - slash - `?....` ? (something like `http://localhost:9100/?...`)

Comment: don't know about the port but the rest looks fine

Comment: Why is there a \ before every `&`? Edit: Hmm. Can't get the formatting to work right for `\``

Comment: The curl above works, the \ is to escape the & on the command line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) provides all the sundry details:

[3.2.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.2)

> If the abs_path is not present in the URL, it MUST be given as "/"
>   when used as a Request-URI for a resource (section 5.1.2).

[14.23](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23)

> A client MUST include a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request
>   messages .

Comment: Apparently web servers ignore this rule though.  I could telnet to a few without the header and getting results.  It seems like everyone is implementing the standard to their liking.

Comment: Depends of you use `HTTP 1.1` or `1.0`, in `1.0` `Host` header is not required.

Comment: (Thanks Burhan... it seems like 1.0 is happy without the Host: part.)  Do you guys have a suggestion around this -- what do I do if the vendor does not want to fix the issue??

Comment: Pfff, writing some kind of proxy is the only thing I can think about.

Comment: This is quite a fundamental issue - you should impose on your vendor to fix it. One alternative is to write your own proxy; but this is not a solution since you don't know what else is broken in the implementation. For example, maybe its not sending the appropriate `CRLF`?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [HTTP1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23), the `Host:` header field is mandatory. <strike>The leading slash isn't required.</strike>It turns out the leading slash is required too.

Comment: I agree with the Host: field according to the spec.

Comment: Indeed... the slash must be there.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with it - <strike>the slash shouldn't be required</strike>.

I stand corrected, the slash is required.

Comment: Are you certain about that? An HTTP GET request is usually different from what you might type in your browser address bar.